# El buzon de correo proporcionado no cumple con RFC 2822. 3.6.2

Tags: php, laravel

Este es mi controlador. Que realizo para la recuperacion de la contraseña la cual la envian a nuestro mailtrap. Pero al tratar de hacerlo me dice que la direccion proporcionada no cumple con RFC 2822 esto lo probe en otro proyecto usando el arcihivo .ENV que se encuentra aqui y si lo envia. El controlador tendra algun error?

```
function recoverylogin(Request $request){

      $codigoUsuario = $this->desencriptarCryptoJS($request->input("codigoUsuario"));

      $modelo = new LoginModel();
      $usuario = $modelo->buscarUsuario($codigoUsuario);

      if(!empty($usuario)){

        $claveDB = $usuario->clave;
        $claveDB = $this->desencriptarLaravel($claveDB);
        $correoDestinatario = $usuario->correo_principal;

        Mail::send('emailTemplates.recoveryPassword', ["clave" => $claveDB], function($message) use ($correoDestinatario)  {

            $message->from('sistema.carent@ejemplo.com', 'CARENT')->to($correoDestinatario)->subject('Recuperación de Contraseña');

        });

        if(Mail::failures()){

          $response = array("recovery" => false, "message" => "No se pudo enviar el correo, intente nuevamente.");

        }

        $response = array("recovery" => true, "message" => "Enviamos sus datos a su correo, por favor revise!.");

      }else{

        $response = array("recovery" => false, "message" => "El usuario no existe");

      }

      return $response;

    }
```

Archivo .ENV

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.ejemplo.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=a98*****ab4
MAIL_PASSWORD=644*****cab2
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Comment: ¿Es posible que en `$correoDestinatario` haya espacios al inicio o al final? Si es el caso, intenta con `$correoDestinatario = trim($usuario->correo_principal);`

Answer (score 1):

ese error del RFC, específicamente la sección 3.6.2 ([Ver aquí](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt)), se refiere a los correos de destino en los métodos `to()`, `cc()`, `bcc()`. Verifica si existe algún espacio, caracter extraño, o algo que haga que no se cumpla la construcción de un correo electrónico.

Además, algunos recomendaciones para tu código:

```js
<?php
function recoverylogin(Request $request)
{

    $codigoUsuario = $this->desencriptarCryptoJS($request->codigoUsuario);

    $modelo = new LoginModel(); 
    $usuario = $modelo->buscarUsuario($codigoUsuario);

    // Considerar usar un método estático para buscarUsuario() y evitar crear un nuevo LoginModel y llamar de la siguiente manera
    $usuario = LoginModel::buscarUsuario($codigoUsuario);

    if ($usuario) {

        $claveDB = $usuario->clave;
        $claveDB = $this->desencriptarLaravel($claveDB);
        $correoDestinatario = $usuario->correo_principal;

        Mail::send('emailTemplates.recoveryPassword', ["clave" => $claveDB], function ($message) use ($correoDestinatario) {

            $message->from('sistema.carent@ejemplo.com', 'CARENT')->to($correoDestinatario)->subject('Recuperación de Contraseña');
        });

        if (Mail::failures()) {

            $response = array("recovery" => false, "message" => "No se pudo enviar el correo, intente nuevamente.");
        }

        $response = array("recovery" => true, "message" => "Enviamos sus datos a su correo, por favor revise!.");
    } else {

        $response = array("recovery" => false, "message" => "El usuario no existe");
    }

    return $response;
}
```

1. Considera el método estático de la clase para evitar crear un objeto
2. En el `if()` si `$usuario` lo que trae es `null` (lo que `buscarUsuario()`) el `if()` funcionaría como debe de ser.